# These are some of the types of Azure Devops Repos commit filters can somebody simplify these

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, cloud, repo

Can somebody explain me these types of filters?

What are these types and how these are helpful for developers how this actually works is this on types of merge we do or in some other order?

- Simple history (Default)
- First parent
- Full History
- Full History (simplify merges)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is [a blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/) that explain:

> By default the commit history view in VSTS is filtered to show Simple
> history. In simple history git simplifies the history e.g. In a case
> where a merge commit (commit M) rolls back a change of a previous
> commit (commit P), simple history won’t show commit P since the
> changes associated with it has no impact on the final state of the
> file. These are cases where one can find it very difficult to find
> where and how the changes introduced to a file went missing.
>
> This is where with simplified merges can help. Git keeps all the
> changes associated with the file and when you filter your results by
> “full history”, the hidden commits such as “commit P” would start
> showing up.